# While loops keeps running Python

Tags: python, while-loop

I'm creating a mini game in python where you need to guess the secret safe code.
now I'm working on the logic and just can't seem to get it right.
here's my code:

```
import random, time

user = input("Enter your name: ")
bet_coins = 7000

# ******************
secret_code = ['12', '1', '7', '4']
# ******************
print("Welcome to the safe game, "  + user[0].upper() + user[1::] + ".")
time.sleep(2)
print("Your goal here is to guess the safe key.")
time.sleep(2)
print("Here's how you start:")
time.sleep(2)
user_decision = input("To play send *play*, for rules send *rules*\n").lower()
time.sleep(2)

def checkScore():
    user_guess_fixed = user_guess.split()
    print(user_guess_fixed[1])

**while user_decision != 'play' or user_decision != 'rules':**
    if user_decision == 'play':
            user_guess = input("HERE WE GO! guess the code! \n(remember, 4 blocks, each one is a number between 1-20, e.g '1 2 3 4'):\n")
            checkScore()

    elif user_decision == 'rules':
            print("bad")
    else:
        user_decision = input("Oops, invalid entry. To play send *play*, for rules send *rules*\n").lower()
        time.sleep(2)
```

the current problem is that the while loop keeps running after you guess the code in user_guess.
can anyone help me to fix? CHEERS

Comment: This `or !user_guess` is not valid Python syntax. Additionally, `user_guess` has not yet been defined at the time of this statement, and should throw an error.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed adding the `break` statement and **logic to decide the break**. This might be the answer you are looking for.

```
import random, time

user = input("Enter your name: ")
bet_coins = 7000

# ******************
secret_code = ['12', '1', '7', '4']
# ******************
print("Welcome to the safe game, "  + user[0].upper() + user[1::] + ".")
time.sleep(2)
print("Your goal here is to guess the safe key.")
time.sleep(2)
print("Here's how you start:")
time.sleep(2)
user_decision = input("To play send *play*, for rules send *rules*\n").lower()
time.sleep(2)

def checkScore():
    user_guess_fixed = user_guess.split()
    print(user_guess_fixed[1])
    return user_guess_fixed == secret_code


while user_decision != 'play' or user_decision != 'rules':
    if user_decision == 'play':
        user_guess = input("HERE WE GO! guess the code! \n(remember, 4 blocks, each one is a number between 1-20, e.g '1 2 3 4'):\n")
        if checkScore():
            break
    elif user_decision == 'rules':
        print("bad")
    else:
        user_decision = input("Oops, invalid entry. To play send *play*, for rules send *rules*\n").lower()
        time.sleep(2)
```